# Trouble with scrapy and filling out a form with a drop-down menu

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to complete a simple form with scrapy, but I just can't figure out how to fill it out and submit it.

Here is the HTML of the form:

```
<form action="#" id="historicalQuoteDatePicker" class="ZEITRAUM" method="get">
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="dateStart">Startdatum:</label>
        <input type="text" name="dateStart" id="dateStart" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
        <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="http://i.onvista.de/d.gif" alt="Klicken Sie hier um ein Datum auszuwählen" title="Klicken Sie hier um ein Datum auszuwählen"> 
        <label for="interval">Zeitraum:</label>
        <select name="interval" id="interval">
            <option value="M1">1 Monat</option>
            <option value="M3">3 Monate</option>
            <option value="M6">6 Monate</option>
            <option value="Y1" selected="selected">1 Jahr</option>
            <option value="Y3">3 Jahre</option>
            <option value="Y5">5 Jahre</option>
        </select> 
    </fieldset>
    <span class="button button-purple button-tiny"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Anzeigen"> 
    </span>
</form>
```

I can complete simple search forms just fine. However, with this one I tried everything and it still doesn't work. I tried to use the clickdata parameter, but it needs a 'name' attribute of the button, which isn't given here.

Here is the code that I tried using so far:

```
def history_popup(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
          formxpath="//input[@id='dateStart']",
          formdata={"dateStart":"09.08.2013"},
          callback=self.history_miner)
```

I know this is incomplete, but I hope I am on the right track here. My question: How can I make it click the button as well as select one of the options from the drop-down menu?

Any kind of help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1) FormRequest clicks the first clickable element:

> The policy is to automatically simulate a click, by default, on any form control that looks clickable, like a .

However one can chose the element to be clicked via clickdata but it does not require a name attribute, any attribute will work including the type attribute. In your case you can do this:

```
clickdata = { "type": "Submit" }
```

2) You can "select" one of the options in the drop-down menu the same way you set the value for the inputs, e.i. "select_name": "option_text". Take heed though, this method sets the value of the drop down to whatever you put as option_text, even if the option does not exist.

```
formdata = { "interval" : "Jahr" }
```

3) Lastly the formxpath value MUST point at a form element, otherwise you will get an error. The way FormRequest works is that it finds a form, finds elements IN that form matching the names in formdata and fills those elements with their respective data from formdata. I believe your formxpath should be:

```
formxpath="//form[@id='historicalQuoteDatePicker']"
```

All together now:

```
FormRequest.from_response(
    response,
    formxpath="//form[@id='historicalQuoteDatePicker']",
    formdata={
        "dateStart":"09.08.2013",
        "interval" : "Jahr" },
    clickdata = { "type": "Submit" },
    callback=self.history_miner
    )
```

This has worked for me in the recent past, good luck! Let me know if it works for you.
A not so helpful but sufficient documentation of FormRequest: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response

Comment: What to do if we have to select multiple entries from select tag? @mand